# Append new Element only once on click and save it to local storage html javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwm360z2/188/)!

I am trying to append new Elements to the div, this is working.

My problem is that I want to append the new element only once on button click, and save it to localStorage so that I would not loose the state on refresh or any other action.

```
div {
text-align: center;
}
#Neighborhood {
color: brown;
}
#NewElement {
color: green;
}

<div id="Neighborhood">
    <div id="Neighbor1">Neighbor 1</div>
    <div id="Neighbor2">Neighbor 2</div>
    <div id="Neighbor3">Neighbor 3</div>
</div>
<input type="button"onclick="add_prev();" value="ACTION">​

/* Adds Element BEFORE NeighborElement */
Element.prototype.appendBefore = function (element) {
element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element);
}, false;

/* Adds Element AFTER NeighborElement */
Element.prototype.appendAfter = function (element) {
element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);
}, false;

/* Typical Creation and Setup A New Orphaned Element Object */

add_prev = function () {

var NewElement = document.createElement('div');
NewElement.innerHTML = 'New Element';
NewElement.id = 'NewElement';
NewElement.appendBefore(document.getElementById('Neighbor2'));
}
```

I am thankful for every tip or solution! Cheers!

Comment: you want that every time an element is created, store it on localStorage to retrieve it? 
Also, take care that creating dinamycally elements with same `Id` can cause problems, id must be unique to a single element

Comment: Therefore I want this element to be created only once :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `this` to the `onclick` function. That way, after you do your things, just remove the listener to click or disable the button.

Also, when the page loads, load the information from the storage, if it's true, directly call the function and then disable the button.
Maybe it isn't exaclty what you need, but it can help a lot, you can follow this logic to get there. The code below is just an example.
**OBS**: it won't work well here because `localStorage` is not allowed in StackOverflow.

In this fiddle you can try it better: https://jsfiddle.net/so5u1c4z/ 
On the fiddle above, create the element, then save and reload the page. the element will be there once the page loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 add_prev = function (elem) {
    var NewElement = document.createElement('div');
    NewElement.innerHTML = 'New Element';
    NewElement.id = 'NewElement';
    document.getElementById('Neighbor2').append(NewElement);
   localStorage.setItem('elementCreated', true);
    if (elem){
      $(elem).attr('disabled', true);    
    }
  } 

  var isCreated = localStorage.getItem('elementCreated');
  if (isCreated){
    add_prev();
    $("#btnAdd").attr('disabled', true); 
  }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="add_prev(this);" value="ACTION" id="btnAdd">
<div id="Neighbor2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
can i also create like a second button or element to hide it like toggle?

Comment: yes, you can use `.toggle()` instead of `attr('disabled', ...)` it will make the button hide